# IOS generate and process sine wave using swift

Tags: ios

My requirement is transmitting the data through sound, so I need to generate my own wave based on given text and play it (speaker) using one Iphone device, and another device listening that sound and decode the message from that sound wave (using microphone).

For this which API's are exactly suitable in IOS using swift language for playing our sound buffers and listening simultaneously and decode it.

Comment: Googling for a suitable API would be the answer. SO is meant for specific technical help and not meant for consultancy.

Comment: For your purpose Apple provides "Audio Toolbox" and "CoreAudio" frameworks. The choice is yours that how you use them. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html

Answer (score 0):

finally I got the solution was AVAudioEngine, AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioPCMBuffer classes in swift IOS for generating sound wave using phase modulation.

For decoding AudioInputNode.InstallTapOnBus class.